# Android equivalent of this parse query for ios

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform

I was going through the Parse *anypic* tutorial and coming from an Android background I am suffering to understand the Android equivalent to this Parse query. I have tried for hours and Googled a lot but to no use. It's about displaying your friends' posts on the timeline.

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    // Query for the friends the current user is following
    PFQuery *followingActivitiesQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kPAPActivityClassKey];
    [followingActivitiesQuery whereKey:kPAPActivityTypeKey equalTo:kPAPActivityTypeFollow];
    [followingActivitiesQuery whereKey:kPAPActivityFromUserKey equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

    // Using the activities from the query above, we find all of the photos taken by
    // the friends the current user is following
    PFQuery *photosFromFollowedUsersQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.className];
    [photosFromFollowedUsersQuery whereKey:kPAPPhotoUserKey matchesKey:kPAPActivityToUserKey inQuery:followingActivitiesQuery];
    [photosFromFollowedUsersQuery whereKeyExists:kPAPPhotoPictureKey];

    // We create a second query for the current user's photos
    PFQuery *photosFromCurrentUserQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.className];
    [photosFromCurrentUserQuery whereKey:kPAPPhotoUserKey equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [photosFromCurrentUserQuery whereKeyExists:kPAPPhotoPictureKey];

    // We create a final compound query that will find all of the photos that were
    // taken by the user's friends or by the user
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:photosFromFollowedUsersQuery, photosFromCurrentUserQuery, nil]];
    [query includeKey:kPAPPhotoUserKey];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    . . .
    return query;
}
```

I just want the android equivalent of this line:

```
[photosFromFollowedUsersQuery whereKey:kPAPPhotoUserKey matchesKey:kPAPActivityToUserKey inQuery:followingActivitiesQuery];
```

I looked through the Parse docs and the swift equivalent of the AnyPic project but to no use.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? What issue do you have?

Comment: @rmaddy 
I am not getting this line in the code:[photosFromFollowedUsersQuery whereKey:kPAPPhotoUserKey matchesKey:kPAPActivityToUserKey inQuery:followingActivitiesQuery]; Is this a relational query? Please help with the android equilavent.

Comment: @rmaddy I just want to get the android equivalent of the above mentioned line.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out on my own. The following are equivalent

**iOS**

```
[photosFromFollowedUsersQuery whereKey:kPAPPhotoUserKey matchesKey:kPAPActivityToUserKey inQuery:followingActivitiesQuery];
```

**Android**

```
postsFromFollowedUsersQuery.whereMatchesKeyInQuery(kPAPPhotoUserKey , kPAPActivityToUserKey , followingActivitiesQuery);
```